# Removing tab selection border

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-css

Anyone know how to remove tab selection border?
I mean this one:
[image]
It's not so clear to see but if you focus you can see a gray (should be blue I think) border around presentation.
Anyone knows how to remove it?

Comment: Well, is that really matter? It's thin anyway.

Comment: Might be an issue with CSS. Please add all relevant code to your question. You might also check out your application with [ScenecView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your external CSS file:

```css
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 ;
    -fx-background-radius:0;
}
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-body-color; /* or your own chosen color: this is default */
}
```

You can find the default CSS settings by extracting the `modena.css` file from the `jfxrt.jar` file (in your JDK's `jre/lib/ext` folder): `modena.css` is in `com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena`, or by browsing the source code (current version at time of writing [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)).